# Throttle Twitter API Search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of Twitter usernames which I'm iterating over to get that user's posts since a particular date. More specifically, I'm doing this in Python with Tweepy.

Every time I return the count of tweets I got before hitting rate limit, the number is different. I know Twitter's API v1.1 has 15 minute windows, however I was just able to get 581 statuses. Earlier this morning I was only able to get 120 and 390 tweets. Their documentation seems to indicate

What's my limit, and what's the best way to throttle Tweepy so I don't get a code 88? Is there a better Python library for Twitter?

Comment: There's [an open pull request](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/256) which adds support for detecting rate limit information from Twitter.